# Get all authors per article with for loop

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, api, loops

I am trying to create a data frame with a for loop in python to get data from the arXiv API. It all works except for getting the authors: I am only able to get the first author per paper, as the loop only gets the first result for the  tag. I want to be able to get all authors per paper. Some help would be highly appreciated!

This is the loop I am using:

```
for e in entries:
   article_id=e.find("id").text
   article_title=e.find("title").text
   article_published=e.find("published").text[:-10]
   article_author=e.find("name").text
   df = df.append(pd.Series([article_id, article_title, article_published, article_author, article_summary], index=dfcols), ignore_index=True)
```

This is what the entries look like:

```
<entry>
<id>http://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00993v2</id>
<updated>2020-04-05T17:16:23Z</updated>
<published>2020-03-31T18:08:23Z</published>
<title>Augmented Q Imitation Learning (AQIL)</title>
<summary>  The study of unsupervised learning can be generally divided into two
categories: imitation learning and reinforcement learning. In imitation
learning the machine learns by mimicking the behavior of an expert system
whereas in reinforcement learning the machine learns via direct environment
feedback. Traditional deep reinforcement learning takes a significant time
before the machine starts to converge to an optimal policy. This paper proposes
Augmented Q-Imitation-Learning, a method by which deep reinforcement learning
convergence can be accelerated by applying Q-imitation-learning as the initial
training process in traditional Deep Q-learning.
</summary>
<author>
<name>Xiao Lei Zhang</name>
</author>
<author>
<name>Anish Agarwal</name>
</author>
<arxiv:comment xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">5 pages</arxiv:comment>
<link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00993v2" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
<link href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00993v2" rel="related" title="pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
<arxiv:primary_category scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="cs.LG" xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"></arxiv:primary_category>
<category scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="cs.LG"></category>
<category scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="cs.AI"></category>
</entry>
```

Comment: Please include all `import` lines. You appear to be parsing XML.

Comment: How do you want one-to-many authors laid out in a two-dimensional data frame? Long format with all authors in one column, or wide format of author1, author2, etc.